# FIrebase collection duplicating list

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I create an expense collection in firebase but when I access it in other screen using provider every time I add new item It duplicate the previous item as I continue inserting items it duplicate them?

```
final summaryDataExpense = Provider.of<ExpensesData>(context).expenseList;
final filterByYearExpense = summaryDataExpense
    .where((element) =>
        DateTime.parse(element['itemDate']).year == currentYear)
    .toList();

var totalExpenses = filterByYearExpense.map((e) => e['itemPrice']).toList();
```

totalExpenses return wrong length of the items existed

Comment: can u provide your full code where this method is called...

Comment: I checked..it showing correctly in my app...looks like u are calling that method twice like init and future builder's future....

Comment: I found the error like u said I duplicated it! Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace type of expenseList from List to Set.

Set will take care of the duplicates.

Comment: I don't want to because I will lost data